# How to change vue/vuetify text field color conditionally

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'd like to conditionally apply a text color class in a text field.  The class I want is `red--text`, like this:

```
:class="{ red--text: myModel.someBool }"
```

...but that results in a parse error. The problem is related to the class name, I think, because this works:

```
<v-text-field
  v-model="myModel" label="My Text"
  :class="{ red: myModel.someBool }"
></v-text-field>
```

...but I want to color the text, not the whole field.

Enclosing the desired class name in quotes `'red--text'` prevents the parse error, but has no effect on the color.

Is there a way to get what I want?

Comment: Did you try `:class="{ 'red--text': myModel.someBool }"`?

Comment: @JacksonMiller - yes.  See that I did in the question.  The fix included quoting the class, as well as a few other things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a custom scoped style that applies itself to the input (since the class of v-text-field is applied to a containing div).

```
<style scoped>
  .my-text-style >>> .v-text-field__slot input {
    color: red
  }
</style>
```

This style name can contain hyphens, as long as it is quoted in the class expression.  Bind the class with v-bind...

```
<v-text-field
  v-model="myModel" label="My Text"
  :class="{ 'my-text-style': myModel.someBool }"
></v-text-field>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand.  I don't know what >>> is or what __slot does or why color: red would work (since that's what I'm trying) or how to apply the class name with hyphens (that's also what I'm trying).  Can you explain a little?

Comment: When a <style> tag has the scoped attribute, its CSS will apply to elements of the current component only. If you want a selector in scoped styles to be "deep", i.e. affecting child components, you can use the >>> combinator.
All information can be found here: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.htm

Comment: `color: red` does not work because of vuetify has it is own styles inside component

Comment: `{'red--text': true}` looks good. But vuetify inner styles overlap it.
`{red--text: true}` does not work because of `red--text` is incorrect js object key. With es you can enclose it

Comment: Broken link.  I notice, when I inspect in chrome, I can apply the style (quoted) 'red-text'. The problem is that it (and any other styles) get applied to a div containing the input... `<div class="v-input v-text-field v-input--is-label-active v-input--is-dirty theme--light red--text" ...`

Comment: Also, I'm using `v-bind:class=` now.  I think that is part of the fix.  Would you be willing to explain with a working snippet, that toggles between font colors?

Comment: How many colors do you plan to have? Only red and default? And do you need red? Is it show exception?

Comment: Only two.  One is to show that input value will be hidden from other users.  I might use grey instead of read.

Comment: I just figured out how to use your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: YAW. There are a lot of options how to bind class. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: Sorry - one other note: I needed !important

Comment: thanks @NaN this is great!  Where is this ".v-text-field__slot input" in the docs?  I'm wondering if this same method can be applied to the label & hint sections as well

Answer (score 3):

you can conditionally bind classes like this:

```
:class="myModel.someBool ? 'red--text' : ''"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use v-bind with ternary condition to apply style

```
 <v-text-field
       v-bind:style="{'border': documentData[name] ? 'solid green 1px !important':'solid red 1px!important'}"
       v-model="documentData[name]"
       :label="name"
       :placeholder="value"
        regular/>
```

> Note - You cannot user color for changing text by using.
>   & highlight box color as well as if you use background-color in place of
>   border you can change whole field color.

Answer (score 0):

You might as well set the actual class from data()

```
data: function () {
        return {
            testClass: 'red--text'
        }
    }
```

And bind your text fields class to that value `:class="testClass"`

Then in methods alter the whole class

```
methods: {    
        uploader() {
            this.testClass = 'primary--text'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using methods

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn text :color="tabColor(1)" @click="selectTab(1)">Tab 1</v-btn>
    <v-btn text :color="tabColor(2)" @click="selectTab(2)">Tab 2</v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      currentTab: 1
    };
  },
  methods: {
    selectTab(tab) {
      this.currentTab = tab;
    },
    tabColor(tab) {
      return tab == this.currentTab ? "primary" : "normal";
    },
  },
};

</script>
```